# no object from a class with an empty class constructor

Tags: powershell

I'm playing around with classes, I try to create an object from the class "testresult" and get an error: "Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "0".
I understand the problem is in the first class "testitem", but quite why? There is a standard empty constructor in the class "testitem"?

```
# class definition
class TestItem
{
[bool]$TestResult
[string]$Message
# 1. constructor
TestItem([string]$Message, [bool]$TestResult)
{
    $this.Message = $Message
    $this.TestResult = $TestResult
}
# 2. standard constructor, empty
TestItem() {}
# ToString() overwrite
[string] ToString()
{
    return $this.Message
}
}
# the second class
class TestResult
{
[int]$TotalCount
[int]$PassedCount
[int]$FailedCount
[System.Collections.Generic.IList[TestItem]]$TestResult

# constructor
TestResult()
{
    $this.TestResult = [System.Collections.Generic.IList[TestItem]]::New()
    $this.FailedCount = 0
    $this.PassedCount = 0
    $this.TotalCount = 0
}
[void]Failed([string]$Message)
{
    $this.AddResult($Message,$false)
}
[void]Passed([string]$Message)
{
    $this.AddResult($Message,$true)
}

[void]AddResult([string]$Message, [bool]$Result)
{
    $testItem = [TestItem]::new($Message, $Result)
    $this.TotalCount++
    if($Result)
    {
        $this.PassedCount++
        Write-Verbose "[+]Passed $Message" -Verbose
    }
    else {
        $this.FailedCount++
        Write-Verbose "[-]Failed $Message" -Verbose
    }
    $this.TestResult.Add($testItem)
}
}

$results = [TestResult]::new()
$results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of [`[IList[TestItem]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-6.0) - but the `I` in `IList` stands for *interface* - an *abstract* kind of type which can't actually be instantiated.

You'll want to create a `[List[TestTime]]` - `List` implements all the members declared by the `[IList[TestTime]]` type, but is *concrete*, meaning that we can actually create objects based on it:

```
$this.TestResult = [System.Collections.Generic.List[TestItem]]::new()
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but still a new question: in the TestResult-Class the property: [System.Collections.Generic.IList[TestItem]]$TestResult is of type: IList, which makes sense.
Now, when I delete the standard, empty constructor from the first class: TestItem, why does it work: $this.TestResult = [System.Collections.Generic.List[TestItem]]::new(), having no constructor with the empty signature?

Comment: @Purclot The call to `[List[TestItem]]::new()` doesn't instantiate any `[TestItem]` objects - it just creates a list that _can contain_ `[TestItem]` instances.

Comment: R. Jensen: ok, now I get it, whole the time I thought I was creating an object of this class.